# How can I run a progress bar concurrently with other modules?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I tried to adapt existing code and am not sure where everything should go.

I created a userform, but instead of doing a label for a progress bar I set it up as a list box that is supposed to update as other modules complete.

I have the following code in one module:

```
Sub DoStuff()

    Dim ufUpdate As UUpdate
    Dim dtTime As Date

    'instantiate the userform
    Set ufUpdate = New UUpdate

    'display a step
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data1…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data2…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data3…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data…"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating …"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating …"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating …"

    dtTime = Now
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Now > dtTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating is COMPLETE!"

    Unload ufUpdate

    Set ufUpdate = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have another module to run each module that correlates to each listbox entry in the code above.  I can get the userform to open and run through the code above, but I cannot get it to run concurrently with all of the other updating, which defeats the purpose of this entirely.

My primary concern is this: where do I place the respective coding or how do I alter the above so that it will run concurrently with the data updating modules?

A second question is in regards to updating the listbox entries as they are completed.  As it is now the list box simply creates the entry "blah blah updating data..." and I would like to add an update so that the listbox entry adds a "...Done." at the end of each entry when the correlating data update is finished.

I tried with something like:

```
ufUpdate.ListBox1.List(0) = "blah blah updating...Done."
```

at the end of the code modules for each data module rather than sticking it in the code above.  Will this work or does it go somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have a fake update status module. Add the status update to the code that runs the actual update process. If the code that runs the update is not on the form itself, I normally create a couple of public methods on the form for the update process to use.

On the user form do something simple like this:

```
Public Sub AddStatus(sStatusMessage As String)
   Me.ListBox1.AddItem sStatusMessage
   DoEvents
End Sub

Public Sub MarkAsDone()
   With Me.ListBox1
      .List(.ListCount - 1) = .List(.ListCount - 1) & "  Done."
      DoEvents
   End With
End Sub
```

Then in the code that is actually doing the updates you can do the following:

```
ufUpdate.AddStatus "Updating data 1..."
Call UpdateData1
ufUpdate.MarkAsDone

ufUpdate.AddStatus "Updating data 2..."
Call UpdateData2
ufUpdate.MarkAsDone
```

Comment: This seems to work well, save one small issue.  When the userform is brought up it does not display anything now... the userform opens and all of the data updates, but the userform istelf is just a total white(blank) window.

Comment: Another quick update: apparently if I click on another window the userform and listbox become visible; however, the listbox does not show any of the entries or updating as the code is running.  only found this because I run dual monitors and happened to click on something on the second monitor... So the userform comes up and the code runs, but if I leave excel selected then the userform shows as a blank white box; if I select something outside excel then the uf/lbox show properly, but with no updates shown in the listbox. *shrug*  Could it have anything to do with having screenupdating off?

Comment: Slight fix to the white box problem.  I can get the listbox and uf to show now while the code is running, but I had to insert a repaint command after every data update.  With the DoEvents above I did not have this problem and did not have to add all these repaint lines.  Do you know if the code you gave could be altered to function with DoEvents to see if that works?

Comment: You are correct. `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` prevents the form from updating unless you use `DoEvents` or `Repaint`. I've added `DoEvents` to the form's methods.

Comment: Finally got back to finishing this up and everything is now working great.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option for you just to replace your `DoEvents` with a simple `Call` to your Modules?  so it would look something like this...

```
ufUpdate.ListBox1.AddItem "Updating Data1…"
Call UpdateData1()
ufUpdate.ListBox1.List(0) = "Updating Data1… Done"
```